# Why is there a difference between the stored and queried time in Mongo database using PyMongo client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I have a MongoDB database with `foo` objects. I'd like to record the time that they are added to the database. To do this, my approach is to store a time, add the `foo` to the database and set the start time. When I get the `foo` from the database, the start time attribute should match the time when I added it.

Below is my test which reflects this. The functions are not terribly important as they're essentially `db.collection.insert` or `db.collection.find_one` calls.

```
def test_set_foo_start_time(self):
    import datetime
    t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    foo_id = "42"
    print("\nAdding {0} to the database.".format(t))
    add_foo_to_database(foo_id)
    self.assertIsNotNone(get_foo_from_database(foo_id))
    set_foo_start_time(foo_id, t)
    time = get_foo_from_database(foo_id)['start_time']
    print("Extracting {0} from the database.".format(time))
    self.assertEqual(t, time)
```

When I run my test, I'm surprised to see that it fails:

```
test_set_foo_start_time (test_foo_misc.FooMiscellanyTestCase) ... 
Adding 2016-10-10 17:01:16.559332 to the database.
Extracting 2016-10-10 17:01:16.559000+00:00 from the database.
FAIL
```

where the assertion error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erip/Code/proj/tests/test_foo_misc.py", line 336, in test_set_foo_start_time
    self.assertEqual(t, time)
AssertionError: datet[36 chars], 559332) != datet[36 chars], 559000, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset obj[15 chars]240>)
```

Why is there a difference in the times that are being stored and extracted? I could add a delta to check a range of times, but I'd prefer to store the exact time. How can I fix my test to account for these microsecond differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), date precision is limited to milliseconds (emphasis mine),

> UTC datetime - The int64 is UTC **milliseconds** since the Unix epoch.

There are a few different ways to approach this, but it largely depends on whether you need sub-millisecond precision. If you don't, then you can round or truncate at the millisecond-level:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)
```

You also would want to ensure that there is no carried timezone info (as that can affect your equality check).

If you need sub-millisecond precision, you could

- Store a string-encoded timestamp that you can parse upon querying.

  ```
  datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
  ```

  The upside is you maintain precision.

  The obvious downside here is strings are limited to lexicographic sorting, and this adds another step both pre-insertion and post-query.
- Store a long or double containing the timestamp.

  ```
  t = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
  milli = t.total_seconds() * 1000 # microseconds present here
  ```

  The upside is you maintain precision and can now sort on it correctly.

  The downside is you have an extra processing step again.
- Store the date as a dictionary containing the timestamp as both a BSON UTC datetime (millisecond) plus the sub-millisecond as a double or long

  ```
  dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  t = {
      "utc": dt,
      "micro": dt.microsecond
  }
  ```

  The upside is again you've maintained precision and can (index and) sort on both fields.

  The downside is the processing step and deconstructed time object.

Comment: Solid answer. One note--because of the way `datetime.datetime` is serialized/deserialized (at least in my example), it's necessary to remove the `tzinfo` from the returned object in the `find_one` call. `dt.replace(tzinfo=None)`.